# How to ignore error during mysql import operation

Tags: mysql, import

My sql version is 5.7.30.
I am trying to import a dump into the database.
However i am getting error in between because of which the processs stop.
I tried using -f, -force also in my command, still it does not work.
Any other way for this. My import should continue even if error occurs.

Comment: how about fixing your error? What is it? What is the SQL causing it? What server version was the dump taken from?

Comment: the dump is huge. i am not even able to open the file. there are 626 tables in it which huge amnt of data. server version was 5.6. Does server version causes prblm?

Comment: Well something causing the problem :-). Going forward a single major version shouldn't be a significant problem. Suggest finding a splitter program like [this](https://github.com/kedarvj/mysqldumpsplitter) (untested by me), and split the dump into smaller tables, scripting the load could make it faster and help identify which is causing the problems. Look at disabling FK constraints until all data is loaded.